# Data Multiplication inside a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008 : I have a table with three columns `Ship Qty, Size, Qty`.

We need to update the column `Qty` by multiplying two other columns.

At present this is the data in the table

```
Ship Qty            Size              Qty
2                   1*100  EA         NULL
3                   3*20 ML
```

Expected result after query

```
Ship Qty            Size              Qty
2                   1*100  EA         200
3                   3*20 ML           180
```

1. Split Size to Size1 (Before X) and Size2 (Behind X) (e.g 1X100 EA => Size1 = 1, SIze2=100)
2. Multiply Ship Qty * Size1 * Size2
3. Update Field qty with the result where qty is null or empty

I have no idea, how can I do it inside SQL Server? I am sure a stored procedure would be helpful !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one try. It makes a lot of assumptions, e.g. that no space will occur until AFTER Size2 and that both sides of the * (or X from your description - which is it?) will be convertible to INT.

```
    DECLARE @foo TABLE
    (
        [Ship Qty] INT,
        Size VARCHAR(32),
        Qty INT
    );

    INSERT @foo([Ship Qty], Size)
    SELECT 2, '1*100 EA'
    UNION SELECT 3, '3*20 ML';

    UPDATE @foo SET
        Qty = [Ship Qty] * CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Size, CHARINDEX('*', Size)-1)) * 
        CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(Size, CHARINDEX('*', Size)+1, 
            CHARINDEX(' ', Size)-CHARINDEX('*', Size)))
    WHERE
        CHARINDEX('*', Size) > 0
        AND CHARINDEX(' ', Size) > 0
        AND Qty IS NULL;

    SELECT [Ship Qty], Size, Qty FROM @foo;
```

I strongly recommend storing this data better. Instead of storing "1*100  EA" store 1 in a column, 100 in a column, and EA in a column. This is going to be a nightmare to maintain, never mind to enforce that the size column gets consistent data (and that your formula will work against all future implementations).

I also suggest not having column names with special characters (e.g. spaces). Nobody likes having to type square brackets when they can be avoided.

Finally, if you can enforce the data on input, you should consider a computed column or view. You shouldn't have to constantly go back and update the table after the fact.

Comment: Whether it is updating only Qty which has NULL or Empty ??

Comment: This is a third party database !! I have values as you see in my posting. So, there is no option for me to have a seperate table, probably we can go for temptable variable or temptable

Comment: Then you should tell the third party that they are doing it wrong.

Comment: Added a check against Qty. It is an INT column I assume, in which case it can be NULL but it can't be "empty"... if it is a varchar column and "empty" really means 0-length string, then you can use AND COALESCE(Qty, '') = '' or update those rows first to be NULL.

Comment: Aaron Bertand, you are passing static value .. instead of column name .. that makes me more confuse !! i have shared only two rows of my table value .. i have more than 500 records to be updated

Comment: Seriously? My "static values" are inserting into a @table variable, so you can see a fully functioning script. Take just the UPDATE part and replace @foo with your real table name (but please try it against a copy first).

Comment: @aaron +1 for a valiant crusade to help someone who apparently doesn't want to be helped, only for you to send teh codez

Comment: @JNK thank you. Can't believe how much head->desk, palm->face and teeth-pulling I've done in the last couple of days. Glad it's noticed by someone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed, you could use functions like `patindex` and `substring` to parse the size:

```
select  [Ship Qty]
,       Size
,       [Ship Qty] * Size1 * Size2
from    (
        select  cast(substring(Size, 1, StarPos-1) as int) as Size1
        ,       cast(substring(Size, StarPos+1, SpacePos-StarPos-1) as int) 
                    as Size2
        ,       *
        from    (
                select  patindex('%*%', Size) as StarPos
                ,       patindex('% %', Size) as SpacePos
                ,       *
                from    @t
                ) as SubQueryAlias1
        ) as SubQueryAlias2
```

[Here's a full example at ODATA.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/104309/)

Comment: Whether it is updating only Qty which has NULL or Empty ??

Comment: 1X60 EA
1X60 EA
1X30 EA
1X30 EA
1X100 EA
1X100 EA
60X3 ML
Actual value look like this ..!! Andomar - Your query works great

Comment: declare @t table ([Ship Qty] int, Size varchar(128))
insert @t
          select [Ship Qty], [Size] from PlacedOrderDetails where Qty is Null 

select  [Ship Qty]
,    Size
,    [Ship Qty] * Size1 * Size2
from  (
    select  cast(substring(Size, 1, StarPos-1) as int) as Size1
    ,    cast(substring(Size, StarPos+1, SpacePos-StarPos-1) as int) as Size2
    ,    *
    from  (
        select  patindex('%X%', Size) as StarPos
        ,    patindex('% %', Size) as SpacePos
        ,    *
        from  @t
        ) as SubQueryAlias1
    ) as SubQueryAlias1

Comment: i made a little change on your query !! But i need to Update - Instead of Insert into and also i face an exception error : Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '14.7' to data type int.

Comment: For the size : 1X14.7 GM - Throws an exception, because you have varchar datatype ?? How to resolve this ??

Comment: Your sample data should illustrate all edge cases. If you have decimals, not just ints, you should say that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `PARSENAME`

```
-- create simple data, copy from Aaron Bertrand
DECLARE @foo TABLE
(
    [Ship Qty] INT,
    Size VARCHAR(32),
    Qty INT
);

INSERT @foo([Ship Qty], Size)
SELECT 2, '1*100 EA'
UNION SELECT 3, '3*20 ML'
UNION SELECT 3, '1*4.7 ML';

-- calcuate Qty    
WITH f AS
(SELECT  [Ship Qty],'[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Size,'*','].['),' ','].[')+']' as size,Qty
 FROM @foo
 )
SELECT  [Ship Qty],PARSENAME(size,3) as Size1,PARSENAME(size,2) as Size2,
     1.0*[Ship Qty] * PARSENAME(size,3) * PARSENAME(size,2) AS Qty
FROM    f
```

Comment: i am going by Aaron ..!! Aaron's query is doing great !! Only issue i am facing is that, i need to update the query

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @foo TABLE
(
Id int,
[Ship Qty] INT,
Size VARCHAR(32),
Qty Float
);

INSERT @foo( Id, [Ship Qty], Size)

select Id,[Ship Qty], [Size] from PlacedOrderDetails where Qty is Null ;
 UPDATE @foo 
 SET Qty = [Ship Qty] * CONVERT(INT, LEFT(Size, CHARINDEX('X', Size)-1)) * CONVERT(Float, SUBSTRING(Size, CHARINDEX('X', Size)+1,              CHARINDEX(' ', Size)-CHARINDEX('X', Size)))
WHERE         CHARINDEX('X', Size) > 0         AND CHARINDEX(' ', Size) > 0         AND Qty IS NULL;

SELECT Id,[Ship Qty],Size, Qty FROM @foo;

-- ***********
-- This query results great
-- Issue is that, It is inserting into Temp Table
-- I want to update it instantly on the Parent Table : PlacedOrderDetails

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody suggested computed column.
I do agree with Aaron re normalising data structure. One column should not have 2 dimensions and a type. This should be 3 columns. This should not be allowed in database.

As for computed column - this will save on triggers. 
In SQL Server, go into table, modify column QTY and set "Computed Column Specification" to desired function. 
You can check more about computed columns here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx